# Display text in center of doughnut

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, chart.js

How to display the corresponding data item of a section on hover in ChartJS?
It shouldn't display anything initially but on hover, it should display the data item of the corresponding section of the doughnut in the center.
Something like this:
https://giphy.com/gifs/pj3umMCJnx3yGUneis/fullscreen

Answer (score 2):

If you could share some of your code that would help quite a bit, but not having used Chart.js I did some searching and found this:

https://jsfiddle.net/cmyker/ooxdL2vj/

```
Chart.pluginService.register({
  beforeDraw: function(chart) {
    var width = chart.chart.width,
        height = chart.chart.height,
        ctx = chart.chart.ctx;

    ctx.restore();
    var fontSize = (height / 114).toFixed(2);
    ctx.font = fontSize + "em sans-serif";
    ctx.textBaseline = "middle";

    var text = "75%",
        textX = Math.round((width - ctx.measureText(text).width) / 2),
        textY = height / 2;

    ctx.fillText(text, textX, textY);
    ctx.save();
  }
});
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I'm fairly new to ChartJS as well, my code is a big mess but I had managed to display the text in the center. But, I want it to dynamically change on hover (like in the example GIF). 
Thank you for your time and help.